# Filling a shape with a gradient in CGContext

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cgcontext

I want to fill a polygon shape that I have drawn via Core Graphics with a linear CGGradient.  The CGContextDrawLinearGradient function draws a gradient from one point to another but it fills the entire view.  How can I display the gradient only inside the polygon shape I have drawn?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can construct a CGMutablePath in your desired shape then use it to clip to the region you want to display, something like...

```
// Construct yourClipPath

CGContextAddPath(yourContext, yourClipPath);
CGContextClosePath(yourContext);
CGContextClip(yourContext);

// Draw Your Gradient
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I figured out that I had to call CGContextSaveGState/CGContextRestoreGState to unclip the region.